# Не отключаются по инструкции Microsoft мешающие ключевые слова

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Имеется большой legacy проект. При компиляции с 20-м стандартом ругается на имена функций or и and, которые на кой-то ляд сделали ключевыми словами. На сайте Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/logical-or-operator-pipe-pipe?view=msvc-160 написано, что данные слова в силе только если в настройках проекта поставлено /permissive- (режим совместимости: да) ИЛИ /Za (отключить расширения языка: да). Разумеется, я режим совместимости и расширения языка выставил в нет, но всё равно не компилируется!

> error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: ||

Когда я отключил вышеуказанное, имена этих функций обрели подсветку как у других, словно теперь эти слова стали расцениваться Intellisense как имена. Но компилятор так не думает. И кстати макросами они не считаются, если верить Intellisense.

Как это решить? Исправлять имя символа очень трудозатратно, придётся перелопатить все исходники, которые писал тем более не я. А 20-й стандарт очень хочется.

Comment: Ну, можно попробовать перешибить чем-то вроде `#define or OR` — по сути, переименуя... Но это так себе решение. Но неужели `/permissive` не действует? У меня на VC++2019 сработало.

Comment: Вы внимательно читали свою ссылку? *In Microsoft C++, the /permissive- or /Za compiler option is required **to enable** the alternative spelling.* — `/permissive-` нужен, чтоб `or`  работало как `||`, а не наоборот...

Comment: @Harry, ну правильно: "/permissive-" это "да", я поставил "нет"; /Za это "да", я поставил так же "нет". Я попробовал варианты и с да и с нет - исход один. Может быть, какие-то другие настройки проекта влияют, их много не по умолчанию. undef не сработал (мало ли, решил проверить). VS тоже 19-ая

Comment: Забавно, что хоть "неразрешённые" имена подсвечиваются, как и все остальные, найти все ссылки/переименовать их не доступно в опциях)) Переименовать символ ещё сложнее, чем думал...

Comment: Заменить имя функции во всех исходных кодах не сложно. Или с командной строки `\<or\>` -> `or_`. Или сделать рефакторинг имени функции внутри Студии. Работы на пять минут.

Comment: Еще стоит обновить VS до 2022, в ней поддержка С++ 20 допилена .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-150 интересно сказано, что /permissive должен находиться после любого параметра, который задает /permissive- неявно. В компилируемом проекте множество настроек не по умолчанию, глядишь, что-то к этим неявно задающим и относится. Я в VS в разделе "Командная строка" в поле "Дополнительные параметры" повторил установленный /permissive. Получилось, что оно идёт после всех параметров командной строки и поэтому "последнее слово" за /permissive. И действительно, после этого ошибки с or/and ушли (и появились другие, сложные, внутри используемой древней версии boost =), но это уже совсем другая история).

Answer (score 2):

Как пишут сами Microsoft, достаточно применить `/permissive`.

Чтобы не было утверждений, что это не так, вот как это выглядит в VC++2019 — тут и исходный текст, и два варианта компиляции...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ответ картинкой?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Нет, ответ текстом. Картинкой - ответ на возражения, что у ТС в VC++19 этот метод не работает. Это просто иллюстрация, чтоб не быть голословным. Ответ я давал в комментариях, но там же ТС ответил, что это не работает. Как я могу доказать свою правоту иначе?

Comment: *Как пишут сами Microsoft, достаточно применить /permissive.* - ну так ОП это уже в самом вопросе уже написал и даже ссылку на документацию дал.

Comment: @user7860670 Но он утверждал, что это не работает. Я доказываю, что он что-то неверно делает, и что этот способ работает. Собственно, если бы в комментарии можно было вставлять картинки, я бы ответ и не писал. А куда-то грузить и делать ссылку - мороки много :)

Comment: В простом проекте без настроек конечно сработает, но существуют, как я выяснил здесь https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-150, параметры, задающие permissive- неявно. И чтобы их нивелировать, надо повторить /permissive после всех них

Answer (score 1):

`or` и `and` присоединились к [пачке ключевых слов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) уже давно, и каждый новый стандарт насыпает еще. `/permissive` является достаточно грубым костылем, единственной задачей которого является обеспечить работоспособность legacy кода, при этом делающим невозможным полноценное использование новых стандартов. Так что проект придется переделывать. Но это по большей части только косметическая проблема, достаточно легко решаемая посредством замены текста.

А вот среди другие ожидающих вас сюрпризов есть переход на связывание независимых имен при разборе шаблонов, меняющая поведение кода, рассчитывающего на нестандартный поздние связывание, и реализация гарантированных оптимизаций при разных действиях с prvalue объектами и возврате из функций, ломающая код, рассчитывающий на побочные эффекты от вызова конструкторов/деструкторов.

Comment: В качестве очень приятного сюрприза выступила ошибка в глубине древней версии boost, связанная с тем, что в выражении "typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<FunctionObj>::other allocator_type;" rebind не считается шаблоном класса/функции, как говорит компилятор. На 17 стандарте компилировалось